# Procedural conditioning on Teradata

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata

I'm not new to SQL at all but I am with Teradata.
How do you create a condition that will *truncate* a table depending on what *day* it is, using a *dimension table* ?

Here's what I'd do on SQL Server to give you an idea :

```
DECLARE @day_name varchar(20)= (SELECT day_name FROM dim_date WHERE 
date = CAST( GETDATE() as date) )

BEGIN
IF @day_name = 'Friday' PRINT('Today is Friday')
ELSE PRINT('Today is not Friday')
END
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Hugo

Comment: For a start, SQL Server has `DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())` which I believe in Teradata would be `CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT 'eeee')`  Then you just need `IF (X) THEN blah; ELSE blah; END IF;`

Comment: Hey, I'm having a few issues with what you just suggested :
1/ CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT 'eeee') doesn't give the day_name
2/ the logic IF (X) THEN blah; ELSE blah; END IF; does not seem to work
3/ How do you manage variables ?
Thanks !

Comment: `does not seem to work` is one of the last useful statements you can make on a forum like SO. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and possibly https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1148-160K/kdb1472241415822.html

Comment: Wow that was unnecessarily condescending - I was only trying to keep words to a minimum giving the character limitation.
Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Teradata offers `TD_DAY_OF_WEEK({date expression})` returning 1 through 7 where 1 is Sunday. It’s more efficient than using the SYS_CALENDAR view to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the condition as a where-condition in your SQL

```
DELETE yourTable 
WHERE 'Friday' = (SELECT day_name FROM dim_date WHERE "date" = current_date )
```

Comment: That's it ! I guess sometimes you just gotta find a completely different way. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to mark it as correct answer.